# YouTube API : com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden again

Tags: android, youtube-api

This question was answered before, but no details are really present in any answers and I'm having no luck getting to the bottom of it. I have been getting both

com.google.android.apps.watchme signature not valid.  Found:

and

com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden

I think the first is causing the latter. Here is what I have:

directory of application is under yt-watchme.
AndroidManifest.xml has package="com.google.android.apps.watchme"
MainActivity.java has APP_NAME = "WatchMe"

so I go to console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials and I create a project called WatchMe. It gives me an additional name of watchme-1316 on the pulldown when I create it.

I enable the YouTube and Google+ APIs.

I create a keystore with the alias WatchMe. Also tried watchme-1316. What is alias suppose to be?

I create credentials as "OAuth client ID" and as Android app. I've also tried API key, but that doesn't work either. I use keytool to get the SHA1 from the keystore and use com.google.android.apps.watchme as the package name. I've tried using name as WatchMe and watchme-1316. Neither seems to work.

I download the client_secret....json and move it to app/google-services.json.

I build the app and sign it in android studio.

Can someone help me with the whole process of how to successfully sign an Android application? There is no clear step-by-step that I've been able to find. It is very confusing what the Alias should be, credential name, etc.

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow.  You really need to show what you have tried so far (actual code).  Please see [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Double check your requirements and credentials. Please exceute the following:

- You need to get your SHA1 key with "keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android"
- In API console: Create a client id with this key and full package name.
- In API console: Create an Android key with this key and full package name.
- Enable YouTube Data API v3 from console

Here the Official Google Documentation, you can use this document to start your application: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/register#create_project

Also, you can try the sample applications offered by Google: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications#Video_Wall

Comment: I have applied all the same steps to building yt-watchme and I keep getting the

com.google.android.apps.watchme signature not valid

even though I can see and create live events I just can't start them. Always is 403 forbidden.

Comment: It looks like I actually have all the correct permissions. For some reason the stream sent to rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx only shows as good for about 2 seconds then the live control room says no data after that.